# No file descriptor left in emacs

Tags: filesystem, big-sur, emacs

I am using emacs on my mac book pro with Big Sur 11.2.3

And I frequently run into the issue of file descriptors

```
File watching not possible, no file descriptor left: 975
```

After several hours of googling the issue I tried several approaches of updating sysctl options.
currently, my relevant options are:

```
kern.maxfiles: 10485760
kern.maxfilesperproc: 1048576
kern.maxproc: 4096
kern.maxfilesperproc: 1048576
kern.maxprocperuid: 8192
```

and I still get the same error.
`ulimit -a` result:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       2048
-n: file descriptors                1000000
```

Comment: Did you use `lsof` to check how many files are actually open? If you get the error in emacs, can you still open files in other applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this code snippet in src/kqueue.c:

```
  /* Check available file descriptors.  */
#ifdef HAVE_GETRLIMIT
  if (! getrlimit (RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rlim))
    maxfd = rlim.rlim_cur;
  else
#endif /* HAVE_GETRLIMIT  */
    maxfd = 256;

  /* We assume 50 file descriptors are sufficient for the rest of Emacs.  */
  ptrdiff_t watch_list_len = list_length (watch_list);
  if (maxfd - 50 < watch_list_len)
    xsignal2
      (Qfile_notify_error,
       build_string ("File watching not possible, no file descriptor left"),
       make_fixnum (watch_list_len));
```

I would say that you have registered 975 file notifications in Emacs, which exceeds the maximum number of file descriptors on your system: `(975 + 50) > 1024`

I have no idea whether you can change this upper limit. However, I believe 975 file notification requests are, hmm, quite high.

Comment: In the end, the issue was `lsp-mode` creating too much file watches.The limit itself doesn't seem to be increasable.

See this reddit thread for more info https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/mq2znn/no_file_descriptors_left/

Comment: I see. Maybe `lsp-mode` is configurable such a way that it watches directories instead of single files?

Comment: Check out this blog post: https://en.liujiacai.net/2022/09/03/emacs-maxopenfiles/ effectively recompiling Emacs can lift the limit if you add some CFLAGS